# Intellij frequent Synchronization and Indexing Files

Tags: java, intellij-idea, intellij-13

Every time I open My IntelliJ project, it is either `Synchronizing files` or `Indexing Files`. It takes a few minutes for Intellij to complete these I am not able navigate by Command + Click or use `Show Uses` or `Call Hierarchy`.

**Environment Details**

- IntelliJ Version : 2019.3.5 Community Edition (I have seen this issue with previous versions as well)
- OS : MacOs Mojave 10.14.6
- I have a bunch of plugins including Cucumber for java, Gherkin, KeyPrompter, Lombok, Substeps IntelliJ Plugin, Other Bundled Plugins like Android Support, Ant, Git, Gradle and many more.

Can someone help understand why IntelliJ could be Synchronizing and Indexing so often? How do I fix it?

Thanks,
Pavan

Answer (score 0):

Please [report](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/newIssue?project=IDEA) all IntelliJ IDEA indexing issues in YouTrack with the logs attached (Help | Collect Logs and Diagnostic Data) after adding `#com.intellij.util.indexing.FileBasedIndexImpl:trace` in Help | Diagnostic Tools | Debug Log Settings.

Before making the bug report [install the latest IntelliJ IDEA version](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/download/index.html) and double check the issue still persists there.